# Does 'gh auth login' create a GITHUB_TOKEN or GH_TOKEN?

Tags: git, api, github, command-line-interface

GITHUB_TOKEN can be used in automated workflows, and I was wondering if running the cli command `gh auth login` and authenticating successfully create an access token of some kind that can be read from the file system somewhere, and used for things like Github API.

Comment: Yes, a token is created for use by [`gh`](https://cli.github.com/). If you need a token for other kinds of uses, you should [create one](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). Does that answer your question? If so, I can write it as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn It almost answers the question. I was wondering if we can directly use that token for other uses like calling Github API.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75968833/does-gh-auth-login-create-a-github-token-or-gh-token?noredirect=1#comment133990025_75968833) Yes, it's technically possible... but it's a Bad Idea™. A primary benefit of token-based access is to separate access permissions by individual task/concern — and re-using the CLI app's token violates that principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an access token is generated for use by [the GitHub CLI app](https://cli.github.com/) (`gh`) when you login: using the scopes that you granted at the time you approved it for your account.

However, if you need tokens for your own uses then you should [create one](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) for each use case. Re-using [tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_access_token) for other purposes is an anti-pattern:

> If the program or PAT is [compromised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)), the damage will be limited by the permissions available to that PAT, and the PAT itself can easily be revoked to prevent further exploitation.